# AngularJS in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

Yes, I know, IE 7 is dated and does not support modern technology. **Insert classic Microsoft joke**

However I work for a state University and there is a lot of red tape so for the time being we still partially support IE7 (hopefully that won't be the case soon). Also, I'm really curious about this issue.

I have read through Angular's documentation for supporting old versions of IE and for the most part I can get things to work. But oddly enough, a simple Angular application crashes on IE7 if you populate two attributes with data bound content in the same HTML tag.

For instance if I am looping (ng-repeat) through an object to create a link list, this works just fine:

```
<a href="{{event.Link}}">Google</a>
```

But this does not work:

```
<a href="{{event.Link}}" title="{{event.Title}}">Google</a>
```

In fact it crashes the whole application. Any thoughts?

Here is a working Plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/znbXJkhiEQXqhTcyYcU4?p=preview just so you can preview some sample code. When I run that code on a static .html page in an IE 7 browser emulator (browserstack.com), nothing shows, not even the "Hello World". Just the Angular templating brackets.

Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks.

Comment: Try using `ng-class` or `ng-attr-class` it might work.

Comment: Have you tried with each attribute individually? or just href alone. It could just be the class attribute.

Comment: Sorry - that was actually supposed to be `<a href="{{event.Link}}" title="{{event.Title}}">Google</a>`, I am not using the "class" attribute. And yes, I tried with "href" alone, "title" alone and "class" alone. It is only when I combine two.

Comment: Have you tried `ng-attr-title` and `ng-attr-href`?

Comment: Have you tried a version of angularjs that supports IE7?  You are using 1.2.x, 1.2.x drops IE7 support.  1.1.x has IE7 support.

Comment: Ahh - I didn't realize they dropped IE7 support that early, yes when I switch to 1.1.5 (random pick) it started working. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: TheSharpieOne please repost as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Note that they will drop an IE8 support as well in 1.3.x